# Should I use Geofencing on current location or use location.distanceTo?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, geofencing, android-geofence

I have some saved locations on `maps`. So, what I'm trying to do is whenever I enter in the range of 50 meters within those saved locations I should get a  notification.

So, should I use `geofencing` on saved location or `geofencing` on my current location or constantly checking `location.distanceTo` and triggering when the distance is less than 50 meters?

Which one will be the most efficient and reliable?
Also, I'm saving those locations dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use geofence because it has default triggering events. so, when you enter or exit from geofencing area you will get notified in your IntentService. For more info check out [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) link.

Comment: yes, you can not add geofence on current location. are you want to set geofence on current location only for testing purpose? if yes then i have one solution.

Comment: Yes. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If you want to set geofence on current location you can follow this steps:
1) Turn on "Allow mock location" in developers options
2) download [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fly.gps) application.
3) open your app and set geofence(not on current location)
4) now press home button and open fly gps and set location which you had set in your app and the specific action will triggered which you have set in your app.
you also can set geofence on your current location by using this app.
Is it clear explaination or need to be more clear? @karatuno